# Crear una función que permita calcular los meses y días faltantes para cumplir años de los clientes en la base de datos

Tags: sql, postgresql

hice esta función pero creo que esta mal por que al momento de implementarla sale error
función:

```
create or replace function happyBirthday(fecha_nacimiento clientes."fechaNacimiento"%type)
returns  character varying as
$body$
    declare
        mes integer;
        dia integer;
        mesesActuales integer;
        diasActuales integer;
        totalDia integer;
        totalMes integer;
        cumple character varying;
    begin
        mesesActuales:= extract(months from now());
        diasActuales:= extract(days from now());
        mes:= extract (months  from $1);
        dia:= extract(days from $1);
        totalMes:= mesesActuales - mes;
        totalDia:= diasActuales - dia;
        cumple:= 'Faltan '||totalMes ||'meses y' ||totalDia|;
            return cumple;
    end
    $body$
    language plpgsql;
```

[image: sale este error]

Comment: Tienes un pipe  `|` después de `totalDia`. Es cosa de quitalo. (Y luego tendrás que manejar los meses negativos :D)

Comment: Como dice el compañero @ffflabs, ten cuidado con los meses negativos, a nadie le gusta saber que su cumple será dentro de -8 meses :D

Por lo que tendrías que trabajar con módulos (resto) de tu fecha con respecto a los 12 meses, por lo que en el caso de -8 meses, la solución sería -8 % 12 = 4 (dentro de 4 meses).

Comment: Asegúrate de pegar cómo quedó ahora el código completo, la foto de poco nos sirve. Si pones texto podemos tratar de debugguearlo cada uno por su lado.